# How do I add a overlay with gmap3?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

First I init gmap3 with this code.

```
var center = [48.8620722, 2.352047];
$('.map').gmap3({
    center: center,
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

That works great. Then I try to add a overlay when I click a button but nothing happens.

```
$('.map').gmap3({
    action: 'addOverlay',
    content: '<div style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #FF0000; background-color: #00FF00; width:200px; line-height:20px; height: 20px; text-align:center">Hello World !</div>',
    latLng: [48.8620722, 2.352047],
    offset: {
    y: -32,
    x: 12
    }
});
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're mixing something up. I'm not familiar with gmap3 plugin, but after a look into the api documentation, it seems that gmap3 doesn't offer `action` as an option. It [offers](https://gmap3.net/api-map.html) only googleMaps native options.

It would be also helpful, if you could make a jsbin code-example for your problem.